# Is the two-color leapfrog problem in P?

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines

My question is whether a specific decision problem is in P or not. It's straightforwardly in NP. The decision problem is a specific case of the general $k$-color leapfrog problem.

I can already show that when $k=1$, the problem is in P. And when $k$ is unlimited, the problem is NP-complete. I have not been able to find an algorithm for the $k=2$ case, but I suspect it is in P. I am wondering if we can prove that it is in P, or (what would surprise me) that it is in fact NP-complete.

This question springs from an interesting discussion in a question I [previously asked](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/127268/is-the-leapfrog-automata-problem-in-p) on this site.

> **The $k$-color leapfrog problem**. Fix $k$. In a $k$-color leapfrog problem, you are given some number of transparent urns containing colored balls. Each ball is one of $k$ possible colors. You are also supplied with an *agenda*, which is an ordered list of colors, for example "red, red, red, blue, red, green, ...".  The object of the game is to draw balls out of the urns, one at a time, following the sequence of colors specified in the agenda. You can easily see the contents of all urns at all times, and can draw any ball out at will. If you could draw the appropriate color from multiple urns, you may choose which one. The only constraint is that you may not draw from the same urn twice in a row. You win the game if you complete the agenda, otherwise you lose.
>
> The decision problem is whether, for a given arrangement of urns and a given agenda, the game is winnable.

**The 1-color leapfrog problem is in P**. If there is only one color of ball, you can decide it with the following algorithm: at each turn, draw the ball from the urn with the most balls in it (among urns you're allowed to draw from). If the game is winnable at all, this algorithm will win it. (Note that even when $k=1$, a game may still be unwinnable if there's too great a disparity in ball count. For example, the setup ["R", "RRR"] with the agenda "RRRR" is unwinnable.)

**The $\infty$-color leapfrog problem is NP-complete**. See my [previous question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/127268/is-the-leapfrog-automata-problem-in-p) and the dazzling solution provided. You can perform a reduction from SAT using a game with two new urns and three new colors per clause.

**What about 2-color leapfrog?** This is my main question. I suspect the problem is in P, as with the 1-color case, but the 1-color algorithm doesn't seem to generalize — or at least I'm not sure.

**Bonus: What about $k$-color leapfrog?** An interesting higher level question is where exactly the problem becomes hard. Is is still in P when $k=3$, or does the leapfrog game have a phase transition like 2SAT to 3SAT? Is perhaps in P for all finite $k$?  I've been struggling to find an efficient algorithm— I suspect there might be one, just based on how the problem becomes smaller and smaller as you remove balls.

---

**Edit** : *The naive extension does not work.* Note that the "leveling" strategy — generally ensuring that the urns have approximately the same number of balls of each color by removing from the urn that has the most— perfectly solves the $k=1$ case. I expect finding an extension of this strategy will solve the $k=2$ case, but note that one naive extension does not work:

For the scenario where the urns contain [AAB, ABB] and the agenda requires AABBBA, the naive strategy of taking from the legal urn with the most of the requested color does not work. It fails to find a solution despite the fact that this instance is actually solvable. (Similarly, the strategy of taking each color from the urn that has the least amount of the *other* color also fails on this problem instance.)

---

**Update:** In the special case that the agenda has the form $A^m B^n$ $(m,n\geq 1)$, you can determine whether it's solvable in polynomial time by playing two single-color games in series. Briefly put, a single-color game is winnable if and only if the vase with the most balls has at most one more ball than the rest of the vases put together. Equivalently, it's winnable if and only if you can pair up each ball with a ball from another vase, with at most one left over. You can construct a winning sequence of moves given such a pairing: first draw the unpaired ball if any. Then iterate over each pair in an arbitrary order. Because the pairs come from different vases, at least one of them will be legal to draw next; draw it, then the other one. Proceed until you draw all the balls.

Because you can iterate over the pairs in an arbitrary order, you can generally always choose a drawing order such that the last ball comes from the vase of your choice. Or, reversing the drawing order*, that the first ball comes from the vase of your choice.  Hence in the two-color scenario, when the agenda is $A^mB^n$, you can solve it as follows: Pick a vase $V_A$ with an $A$-colored ball and another vase $V_B$ with a $B$-colored ball (if you can't, then there's only one vase and it has multiple balls in it, so the game is unwinnable). If it's possible to win the $A^m$, choose the winning strategy to draw from $V_A$ in the last step. If it's possible to win the $B^n$ game, choose the winning strategy to draw from $V_B$ in the first step. This can all be done and checked in polynomial time, QED.

[*] Actually, reversing a path is not always possible: if the vase with the largest amount has exactly one more ball than the rest of them put together, then you *must* draw from the largest vase first. The proof for how to solve $A^mB^n$ in this case will have to wait.

---

**Update**: By exchanging the notion of urns and colors, you can get the following equivalent formulation:

> *Reformulated leapfrog problem:* Fix $k$. You are given $k$ urns full of different-colored balls, and an agenda which tells you which urn you must draw from at each step. Your goal is to empty all of the urns subject to the constraint that each ball must be a different color from the one before it.

Perhaps rephrasing this way can be useful.  Also in this reformulation, I think the complexity is exposed by supposing you have two urns, where the second urn contains at most two balls.

Comment: It sounds similar to a problem in which you want to find a path in a (directed) graph with specified colors (in order). These type of problems are usually hard (like GRAPH MOTIF, which IIRC is hard for 2 colors even on trees). Your visitation constraint might complicate things a little (or maybe you can avoid it) but a reduction from such a problem might be short and simple.

Comment: @Juho Thanks for the tip! I'll look into color graph path problems; the leapfrog problem is definitely a special case of that. I suspect it's an easier special case, but if I can perform a reduction from GRAPH MOTIF,  that'll establish that it's in fact just as difficult.

Comment: Have you tried dynamic programming? Given $n$ vases each described as a list of colors, our ability to win the game depends on $n+1$ parameters, the index of the active vase (constraint) and $n$ indices of locations in each list which indicate the number of balls we have drawn from each vase. If I'm not missing anything basic, this seems to admit to a straightforward $O(n^3)$ time algorithm (assume for simplicitly that $n$ is a bound on both the number of vases and the number of balls in each vase). It also seems to work for the $\infty$-color problem, so I might be completely off.

Comment: @Ariel I should clarify that there's no order to the balls in each vase---you can see all of them, and pick any one out at will.  The agenda is a separate structure, listing the sequence of colors you must draw (and you can pick which vases). I like your approach, though, and a similar algorithm definitely works for $k=1$ colors. Maybe we can make it work for $k=2$?

Comment: My mistake, I missed the "draw any ball at will". The encoding becomes important here, each vase should be described as a histogram (n-white, m-black) otherwise the previous solution is polynomial.

Comment: @Ariel Can you, please, elaborate on the $O(n^3)$ algorithm from your previous comment? If I understand you right, you will have to fill a $(n + 1)$-dimensional table with $n$ elements in each dimension at the worst case. But it will give an $\Omega(n^{n+1})$ time complexity.

Comment: It seems I wasn't careful enough, so there's no issue with encoding (we can assume that each vase has at most the agenda's length balls of each color, and since the agenda is ordered this means we are allowed a polynomial number of operations in the numerical value of the number of balls in each vase).

Comment: Assuming there is a polynomial algorithm, perhaps there's one that runs in time $O(n^k)$, where $k$ is the number of colors and $n$ is the problem size. This suggests an approach to designing an algorithm---iterate over each color, or even each pair of colors. And it would suggest why the problem becomes harder when the number of colors is unbounded so $k \approx n$.

Comment: As a follow up, note that when the agenda is a simple band of colors, e.g. AAAAAA or AAAAABBBBB, the problem is quite simple because it factors mostly like the $k=1$ case; the hard part is deciding what to do at the junctions between neighboring colors.  If we can find a simple algorithm for the junctions, we can handle each color more or less separately and stitch them together in the end.

Comment: If there are not enough As and Bs in total to cover the letters in the agenda, then clearly the instance is unsolvable. Otherwise, the only way to get stuck is to get into a situation where two adjacent agenda letters can only come from the same urn. So if you can choose urns in sequence so that, while $\ge 2$ A-balls remain in the agenda, you have at least 2 distinct urns $a_1, a_2$ containing 1 or more A-balls, and similarly urns $b_1, b_2$ for B-balls (note $\{a_1, a_2\} \cap \{b_1, b_2\}$ is allowed to be nonempty), you will get a solution. However this can miss some solvable instances.

Comment: The above is not quite right: Once there is only one A left in the agenda, if there is only one urn with A-balls in it and it is also one of the 2 urns with B-balls, then we cannot necessarily choose B-ball urns freely. Still I think this problem can be attacked with a case analysis: Either there is a solution where we never drop below 2 A-ball urns and 2 B-ball urns; or a solution in which some urn becomes the only A-ball urn "first"; or a solution in which some urn becomes the only B-ball urn "first"; or no solution. There are only $O(n^2)$ such cases to consider.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm wondering what counts as a "case" --- is it a game state (i.e. the contents of each urn at a single point in time) or a game path (i.e. a sequence of draws to make)?  Naively, there are a lot of paths --- each game state will generally have multiple ways to arrive at it, and some might not be legally reachable.

Comment: @j_random_hacker If we restrict either the maximum number of urns or the number of balls per urn, the search problem becomes polynomial, but I'm not sure yet that it's polynomial without those restrictions.  In the first case, a game state lists the number of balls of each color in each urn. In the second, the contents of each urn have a constant number of possibilities, so a game state counts how many urns of each content-type there are. In both cases, the number of game states is polynomial in the input.

Comment: A case is a set of additional constraints that we might choose to impose. E.g., "Is there a solution *in which urns 3 and 5 finish with at least 1 A-ball each, and urns 2 and 5 finish with at least 1 B-ball each*?" The idea being to come up with a set of at most polynomially many cases such that (a) any solution to the original problem belongs to at least 1 case in the set, and (b) each of these more constrained problem instances can be solved in poly time -- solving each case would then give a poly-time algorithm. But now I think (b) is harder to achieve than I thought.